# Malicious HTTP POST requests

Tags: php, .htaccess, post

For weeks my site is receiving http POST Requests which are taking it down or making it terribly slowly.

At first i was able to block these requests using htaccess by preventing all POST requests which Referrer are empty or not equal to my domain.

But now he is using a fake referrer as my domain.

All requests have different IPs and different User-Agent.

These are few requests info:

```
IP: 86.131.147.218
HOST:
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
Method: POST
Protocol: HTTP/1.1
Refer: http://zoocine.net/
POST Vars: do=search&story=kiri+S01E02&subaction=search

IP: 82.25.10.2
HOST:
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0
Method: POST
Protocol: HTTP/1.1
Refer: http://zoocine.net/
POST Vars: do=search&story=ghost+adventures+S07E18&subaction=search

IP: 98.233.119.166
HOST:
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0
Method: POST
Protocol: HTTP/1.1
Refer: http://zoocine.net/
POST Vars: do=search&story=game+of+thrones+S07E01&subaction=search
```

Right now i have denied all POST requests but this is also denying my users to search the site, login or use the chat box.

This is my htaccess code right now:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !zoocine\.net [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Is there any way about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Implement CSRF tokens so you know if they're making the requests directly from the server: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet There are multiple PHP libraries that will build CSRF tokens for you.
- Run https://securityheaders.io/ on your website and it will give you directive on what HTTP headers you should set on your site to prevent attacks.

You can also block the specific IP addresses that make such requests, but it won't be manageable if they keep changing the IP address.